# SQL Update Select The multi-part identifier "OLD_SP.Num" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

```
Declare @modCode varchar(3)
SET @modCOde = 'SOR';

UPDATE  Doc_SalesOrder
SET     OLD_SP.Num = NEW_SP.NewNum
FROM    Doc_SalesOrder as OLD_SP
INNER JOIN
(
     Select
       Id,
       dbo.ApplyModuleCode(@modCode,Num) as NewNum 
     From Doc_SalesOrder
     Where Num not LIKE '%'+@modCOde+'%'
)NEW_SP ON OLD_SP.Id = NEW_SP.Id
```

When I  run the query the error is:

> The multi-part identifier "OLD_SP.Num" could not be bound.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
UPDATE  OLD_SP
SET     OLD_SP.Num = NEW_SP.NewNum
FROM    Doc_SalesOrder as OLD_SP /* .... */
```

Or just simply drop the table prefix in the set statement target entirely. There is no ambiguity here.

```
UPDATE  Doc_SalesOrder
SET     Num = NEW_SP.NewNum
FROM    Doc_SalesOrder as OLD_SP /* .... */
```